# Internet explorer sending cookies even though they are blocked?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, cookies, internet-explorer-8

I have a strange problem with an ASP.net website whereby we perform a cookie check to see if cookies are enabled and if not redirect users to a page on enabling cookies etc.
This is working fine in all browsers except for Internet explorer, whereby I get past the page that performs the cookie check without this redirection. I attached the remote debugger to the server and stepped through the code and sure enough, on the line

```
If(Request.Cookies[“CookieSupport”] == null)
```

Request.Cookies contains a cookie by the above name. In fact, it contains three cookies as you would expect for cookies being enabled.

Now, I’ve got into Internet Options, set privacy to ‘Block all cookies’, gone into the developer tools and ensured ‘Disable Cookies’ is checked on the Cache menu and I’ve cleared out all temporary internet files including cookies. I’ve restarted my browser but still this check passes. Oddly, it works consistently in Firefox, Chrome and Opera.

If I go to other sites which support cookies I get a message telling me they are disabled, so this request must be being cached somewhere, but I really don’t see where this is happening. I’ve tried several times through the past couple of days, so its not across the same server session either, and I’ve even restarted IIS on the server to clear down any session data.

Can anyone explain whats gonig on?

Thanks